# How to get jquery-select2 to display html entities correctly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using jquery-select2 4.0.0 and I want to display a text containing an '&'.

This is the code of the option:

```
<option value="123">
   123 - This & That
</option>
```

However, Select2 shows the following as the option text:

```
123 - This &amp; That
```

How can I get Select2 to show the specialchar correctly?

Comment: Just a heads up, this was because of a [bug that we just fixed](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3115) in the new version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can fix that with the help of `escapeMarkup` option.

```
<select id="s2">
    <option value="123">123 - This & That</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#s2').select2({
        escapeMarkup: function (text) { return text; }
    });
});
</script>
```

[**Here's the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/yxL585rc/) on jsfiddle.

You should take a look [at this GitHub issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/585) and look for `escapeMarkup` [on the documentation](https://select2.github.io/options.html).

Comment: @Benni I'm glad my answer was useful. Please take a moment to check how to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/266555) if this answer solved your issue. Thanks!

Comment: I know I am replying late on this answer, but won't this enable XSS possibility and has security vulnerability? Example if we are escaping user input as select2 option, then user can inject malacious script on it right?

Comment: try this select option:

`<option value="123">123 <script>alert('script');</script> - This & That</option>`

Comment: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3115#issuecomment-77664168